# Web API exception handling using FilterAttributes

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-web-api2

I have a filter that captures errors and logs them, but I would like it to return the correct **HttpStatusCode** so that my client application can display a decent error message.
Currently, in the overridden **OnException** method of my filter attribute, I try to get the statuscode by casting the exception as a **HttpException**.
This looks like this:

```
public class LogExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{

    // Private properties
    private readonly ILogProvider _logger;

    /// <summary>
    /// Our default constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger"></param>
    public LogExceptionFilterAttribute(ILogProvider logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when an exception has been thrown
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context</param>
    public override async void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {

        // Get our user
        var requestContext = context.Request.GetRequestContext();
        var user = requestContext.Principal.Identity;

        // Create our response
        var message = await _logger.ErrorAsync(context.Exception, user);
        var content = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent(message),
            StatusCode = GetStatusCodeFromException(context)
        };

        // Assign our response to our context
        context.Response = content;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a status code from an error
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static HttpStatusCode GetStatusCodeFromException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {

        // Cast the exception as an HttpException
        var exception = context.Exception as HttpException;

        // If we don't have an exception
        if (exception != null)
        {

            // Return the HttpException code
            return (HttpStatusCode)exception.GetHttpCode();
        }

        // Return Internal Server Error
        return HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }
}
```

I realise that most errors cannot be cast as **HttpExceptions** so will the status code returned will always be 500.

To fix this, I would like to add a check for any exception type and handle them accordingly.
I decided the best way to do this was to create a switch statement like this:

```
private static HttpStatusCode GetStatusCodeFromException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
{

    // Cast the exception as an HttpException
    var exception = context.Exception as HttpException;

    // If there is still an exception, return the code
    if (exception != null)
        return (HttpStatusCode)exception.GetHttpCode();

    // Otherwise, work out what type of error we have
    switch(context.Exception.GetType().ToString())
    {
        case "NullReferenceException":
            return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        default:
            return HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }
}
```

But now I am not sure if that is correct.
Could someone either help me expand this out or tell me of a better way of doing this?

Comment: I hope catching `NullReferenceException` is a typo.

Comment: `NullReferenceException` is not bad request. That's perfect `InternalServerError`.

Comment: The normal status from http is 200 Done.  So you do not want to create an exception for 200.  The status code will vary depending on the server so you may not always get 500 for the same error.  People who maintain server do not want hackers to reverse engineer error messages so they provide as little info as possible about the true error.

Comment: It was just an example, I want to set up for all exception types. for example NotFoundException I want to return 404...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of comparing the type on its name, it is much safer to actually check the type itself:

```
if (context.Exception is NullReferenceException)
{
    return HttpStatusCode.BadProgrammer;
}
else
{
    return HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
}
```

Comment: can I not do it as a switch statement? It seems like doing an if statement would be massive

Comment: [If you have C#7, yes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/). Search for "Switch statements with patterns".

Answer (score 0):

I have marked @Patrick Hofman's answer as correct, but I used c#7 to make a switch statement, which looks like this:

```
private static HttpStatusCode GetStatusCodeFromException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
{

    // Cast the exception as an HttpException
    var exception = context.Exception as HttpException;

    // If there is still an exception, return the code
    if (exception != null)
        return (HttpStatusCode)exception.GetHttpCode();

    // Witch on the exception type
    switch (context.Exception)
    {
        case ObjectNotFoundException ex:
            return HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        default:
            return HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }
}
```

Comment: please verify that this actually works... as i cant get to complie

Comment: What is it moaning about?

Comment: "class name is not valid at this point" what ever you put in case, aka have more than one case per return match and you will see what i mean.